# How to replace a character value with number in a R data frame?

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset with few variables that contain the two values Correct/ Incorrect
I want to replace all Correct with 1 and Incorrect with zero.

The datatype of the variable is character. I tried gsub and replace which didnt work. Can anyone help me with this.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `ifelse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == "correct", 1, 0))
df

 x y z
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 0
3 1 1 1
4 0 0 1
5 0 1 0
6 0 0 1
```

Or to only apply to some columns:

```
cols <- c("x", "z")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.integer(x == "correct"))
df
  x         y z
1 1   correct 1
2 1   correct 0
3 1   correct 1
4 0 incorrect 1
5 0   correct 0
6 0 incorrect 1
```

Where

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("correct", "correct", "correct", "incorrect", "incorrect", "incorrect"), 
  y = c("correct", "correct", "correct", "incorrect", "correct", "incorrect"), 
  z = c("correct", "incorrect", "correct", "correct", "incorrect", "correct")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a logical, and convert the logical to numeric. `TRUE` always equals one and `FALSE` zero.

```
a <- c('Correct', 'Incorrect', 'Correct')

sapply(a=='Correct', as.numeric)

[1] 1 0 1
```

If you want to apply it to a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('Correct', 'Incorrect', 'Correct'), b=c('Correct', 'Incorrect', 'Incorrect'))

df

          a         b
1   Correct   Correct
2 Incorrect Incorrect
3   Correct Incorrect

matrix(sapply(df=='Correct', as.numeric), ncol = ncol(df))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the columns into factors and then to numeric without specifying a condition.

```
#Create data frame

> df <- data.frame(a = c("correct", "correct", "correct"), 
                   b = c("incorrect", "correct", "incorrect") )
> df
        a         b
1 correct incorrect
2 correct   correct
3 correct incorrect

#Convert character columns to numeric using apply:
> df2 <- as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(L){as.numeric(as.factor(L))}))
> df2
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 1
3 1 2
```